# How Nested For loop works

Tags: python

```
def SNP(seq1, seq2):
    result = []
    counter = 0
    for position, base in enumerate(seq1):
        for position2, base2 in enumerate(seq2):
            if base != base2:
                result.append(position)
                result.append(base)
                result.append(base2)
                counter += 1

                if counter == 2:
                    return None

    result2 = tuple(result)
    return result2

print(SNP('AAGCCTA', 'AAGCTTA'))
```

If the "if statement" is invalid, the loop starts again with the 2nd for loop which I did not intend to...

So the question is after the if statement, how should I let the code start again with the first loop instead of 2nd for loop after 1 loop?

Comment: You need to [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) out of current loop.

Comment: @Rogalski Do you mean to use break ? in the 2nd for loop?? I am not sure how to break out of the current loop..

Answer (score 0):

You simply neead a break in the `if` block, like this

```
if base != base2:
    result.append(position)
    result.append(base)
    result.append(base2)
    counter += 1

    if counter == 2:
        return None
else:
   break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def SNP(seq1, seq2):
result = []
counter = 0
for position, base in enumerate(seq1):
    for position2, base2 in enumerate(seq2):
        if base != base2:
            result.append(position)
            result.append(base)
            result.append(base2)
            counter += 1

            if counter == 2:
                break

result2 = tuple(result)
return result2
```

Added the break to the if. Sorry if that's the wrong if statement.